# a jacket which is to be worn

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

Can one say

1. This is a jacket which is to wear in cold weather.
2. This is a jacket which is to be worn in cold weather.
3. This is a jacket which is for wearing in cold weather.
4. This is a jacket to wear in cold weather.
5. This is a jacket to be worn in cold weather.
6. This is a jacket for wearing in cold weather.

?

Do (2) and (5) carry the idea of obligation? (The jacket has to be worn in cold weather.)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only your first example

> This is a jacket which is to wear in cold weather.

sounds a little awkward, but in understandable.  All your other examples are perfect and get used all the time.

There is not *obligation* involved in (2) and (5).  If you wanted that specific meaning you might say

> This jacket is **only** to be worn in cold weather.